# Making a <div> with a drop shadow only on the left and right sides

Tags: css, dropshadow

My goal is to add a drop shadow to the left and to the right side of a `#container div`, which is 960px wide.

The `#container` itself contains a header, a nav menu, main content, sidebar, and foot. But the header itself juts out of the `#container` with a custom width due to a graphic.

As such, it does not get a drop shadow added to its right and left. Only the nav menu down needs the drop. This is because the header is set to a custom width, and juts out beyond the `#container` itself. A drop shadow to the left and right of a thing that already juts out would ruin the aesthetics.

For better visualization, my site looks similar to http://www.doubleyourdating.com/, but the header element juts out on both sides.

I've tried to add a drop shadow to the left and to the right side of the `#container`, from the nav menu down with the following solutions:

1. I Photoshopped a 1px high, 1010px wide image which contains a 25px "fade" on opposite ends. I CSS'd that as the `#container div background-image`, but, probably because the `#container` itself is set to 960px wide, the 1010px wide background can't show up. Note that changing the 960px width will create a cascade of death in this simple 2 column layout.
2. I tried CSSing up a makeshift shadow box div "around" the container div, but that isn't working because my header has a custom width that extends wider than the container.

How do I make this work?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is much more appropriate here that " it's all ***

Answer (score 41):

You could try something like this:

```
box-shadow: 6px 0px 5px -5px #999, -6px 0px 5px -5px #999;
```

Of course, [mess around with the values](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/6UFX7/8090/) until it suits you.

Comment: This doesn't get rid of the top and bottom shadow, just reduces it.

Comment: This is not a valid answer. It's sort of a hack. It still keeps the shadow. For those who actually want to accomplish the goal, this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ChrisStephens Code has been revised.

Comment: oh yeah, awesome, this looks like the real answer to me. I modified your fiddler to add it to the situation i had to deal with and it works well: http://jsfiddle.net/cstephe/N9Tpf/1/

Answer (score -2):

Single line of code :

```
box-shadow: 4px 0 2px #222,  -4px 0 2px #222;
```

Just insert in corresponding css style element 
Done!